# Normalize object in a Akeneo EventListener

Tags: symfony, events, rabbitmq, listener, akeneo

I'm currently trying to normalize an object (product in this scenario) in an Akeneo Event listener.
The main goal is to be able to publish as an event the full edited product on a RabbitMQ queue when a modification occurs.

I'm currently struggling with normalization, I would like to obtain a "flat object" with all the object's fields and value inside but it's doesn't go very well.

I firstly set an event listener in the services configuration:
(services.yml)

```
parameters:
    pim_ce_dev_src_folder_location: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev'
services:
    my.listener:
        class: Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\EventListener\ProductModificationListener
        arguments:
            - '@swiftmailer.mailer'
            - '@logger'
            - '@pim_catalog.normalizer.standard.product'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: akeneo.storage.post_save, method: onPostSave }
```

And defined the listener service:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Model\Product;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Normalizer\Standard\ProductNormalizer;

class ProductModificationListener
{
    private $mailer;
    private $logger;
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, LoggerInterface $logger, ProductNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onPostSave(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        $subject = $event->getSubject();

        if (!$subject instanceof Product) {
            // don't do anything if it's not a product
            return;
        }

        $this->logger->info($subject->getId());

        $normalizedObject = $this->normalizer->normalize($subject);
        $this->logger->info($normalizedObject);
    }
}
```

When I try to normalize the product (after a product edition), I got this error:

```
[2021-01-27 15:54:54] app.INFO: 1207 [] []
[2021-01-27 15:54:54] app.INFO: 1207 [] []
[2021-01-27 15:54:54] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotNormalizableValueException: "Could not normalize object of type "Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Value\ScalarValue", no supporting normalizer found." at /srv/pim/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php line 178 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Exception\\NotNormalizableValueException(code: 0): Could not normalize object of type \"Akeneo\\Pim\\Enrichment\\Component\\Product\\Value\\ScalarValue\", no supporting normalizer found. at /srv/pim/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php:178)"} []
[2021-01-27 15:54:54] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\NotNormalizableValueException: "Could not normalize object of type "Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Value\ScalarValue", no supporting normalizer found." at /srv/pim/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php line 178 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Exception\\NotNormalizableValueException(code: 0): Could not normalize object of type \"Akeneo\\Pim\\Enrichment\\Component\\Product\\Value\\ScalarValue\", no supporting normalizer found. at /srv/pim/vendor/symfony/serializer/Serializer.php:178)"} []
```

Is it the best approach to use normalization and if yes, how can I implement it? (quite sure I'm just missing an argument or something like that)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, when you say "it's not working" what do you mean? Do you have errors?

Comment: Hi, It's more an "I don't know how to make it working" issue, I'm trying several different (and random) things but always with the same results, nothing; I just updated the question with the latest approach I tried and the linked error. Merci !

Comment: Thanks. Do you need to normalize this object "Product\Value\ScalarValue"? if not use serialization groups to skip normalization of this object. If yes create a custom normalizer for this object

Answer (score 0):

So, I find the good Normalizer, it's the "Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Normalizer\InternalApi\ProductNormalizer
"

That code is working:

```
parameters:
    pim_ce_dev_src_folder_location: '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev'
services:
    my.listener:
        class: Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\EventListener\ProductModificationListener
        arguments:
            - '@swiftmailer.mailer'
            - '@logger'
            - '@pim_enrich.normalizer.product'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: akeneo.storage.post_save, method: onPostSave }
```

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Model\Product;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Akeneo\Pim\Enrichment\Component\Product\Normalizer\InternalApi\ProductNormalizer;

class ProductModificationListener
{
    private $mailer;
    private $logger;
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, LoggerInterface $logger, ProductNormalizer $normalizer)
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onPostSave(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        $subject = $event->getSubject();

        if (!$subject instanceof Product) {
            // don't do anything if it's not a product
            return;
        }

        $this->logger->info($subject->getId());

        $normalizedObject = $this->normalizer->normalize($subject, 'json');
        $json = json_encode($normalizedObject);
        $this->logger->info($json);
    }
}
```

And this is the output: https://jsonblob.com/1bd43ac3-60e6-11eb-a1e4-25c2119d0903